# Probability Loaded die

Tags: probability

A die is loaded so that 5 and 6 are both twice as likely to occur as the other numbers. The die is thrown six time.

Find the probability that we get a 5 three or four times.

This is what I have done so far: ${}_6C_3  (2/8)^3 (6/8)^3 + {}_6C_4  (2/8)^4  (6/8)^2$.

The answer should be 135/512

Comment: Good homework problem.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know probability of it occuring exactly twice is 1215/4096...Bernoulli trials. I tried adding probabilites of exactly 3 and 4 times etc but no good. Answer is supposed to be 135/512. Any help I'd be delighed

Comment: Read about the binomial distribution.

Comment: I have done but I just can't get it to work!!! What am I missing???

Comment: @cows1990 You should edit the question to include your detailed calculations with the binomial distribution. A proper answer to this question will need to take into account exactly where you're going wrong.

Comment: 6C3 x (2/8)^3x (6/8)^4 + 6C4 x (2/8)^4 x (6/8)^2  all over 6C3 +6C4

Answer (score 1):

Let's check the answer you were given:

Regard the probability of getting a 5 as a success, which has
probability $p = 2/8 = 1/4$ on any one toss. Then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 6,\, p=1/4)$ counts the 5's in $n = 6$ tosses. You want

$$P(X = 3) + P(X = 4) = {6\choose3}(1/4)^3(3/4)^3 + {6 \choose 4}(1/4)^4(3/4)^2\\=\frac{20(27)}{4096} + \frac{15(9)}{4096} = \frac{675}{4096}
=  0.1647949$$

In R statistical software:

```
 dbinom(3, 6, 1/4) + dbinom(4, 6, 1/4)
 ## 0.1647949
```

However $\frac{135}{512} =  0.3276699.$ So I don't think that is really the
correct answer to the problem you have stated.

Here is a plot of the PDF.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that...ya that's the answer in the solutions book anyway...be it right or wrong

Comment: I hope you're not waiting for someone to show $135/512$ is the correct answer. That will take a while.